# How to get a URL by adding additional segment to an existing URL

Tags: html, url, href

Let's say the current URL is `www.mysite.com/cabinet`. I have an anchor element href of which I need to set so that after clicking the link the url becomes `www.mysite.com/cabinet/inbox/1/0`. I have tried the following:

```
<a href="./inbox/1/0"/>
```

But what I get is `www.mysite.com/inbox/1/0`. Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: What is an `anchor element href`?

Comment: `cabinet` needs a trailing slash to make `./inbox` work as a relative link. See my answer below

Comment: @jotik, by that I mean an anchor element (<a/>) with href attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// "./" refers to your root ("/") 
www.mysite.com/cabinet

// Add a trialing slash -> ./ refers to "/cabinet/"
// ./inbox is now a child of "/cabinet"
www.mysite.com/cabinet/
```

Comment: Huh, I must be a stupid. Why didn't I just write <a href="/cabinet/inbox/1/0"/>. Thanks for the clue